# Thunderbird: Quickfilter on NOT Starred and not watched mails

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I' like to (quick)filter in Thunderbird all my mails which I have not starred and which I do not watch already. Is there any option to archive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the board options which seem not to provide the possibility to combine filters with "not" also to seems to be no (quick)filter for read.

Beside this, looking at filters and not quickfilters, there is no option to select "starred" messages.

Finally looking at add-ons there seems to be o [ne which filters on watched messages](https://github.com/tmatz/thunderbird-qfb-watched-addon) but also this can not combined with "not". Last, in a note of this add-on it is mentioned that due to changes with version 68 this add-will not be available any more.

Looking at the code it seems to nail down to `thread.flags & 0x100` to get watched messages. This raises the hope that there is also a hex code to be used for "starred" if so I would assume that this could be all archived by coding, if I have not overseen the onboard option.

Best would be a build in quckfilter on "watched" messages and the option to invert the complete quickfilter (which could be a combination of various options provided by the quickfilters).

Just for completeness: the option to invert tags does not fulfill the requirement since there is no chance to get "not tagged messages".